# Why executing exe file in Command Prompt keep opening new window

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line

I'm using Windows 10, open Command Prompt, cd to a folder which contains test.exe file, when I type "test.exe" and press Enter, the file is always executed in a new window. This does not happen with other computers of mine.

Why does this behavior happen on this computer and how to change it?

UPDATE: the test.exe is a console application. In the other computers of mine, there is no new window opened, the file is execute in the same window of the Command Prompt, that the behavior I expect.

Comment: I'd be interested to run Process Monitor - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon - start capturing. Launch a command prompt, then CD to the dir and launch the exe, stop capturing in Process Monitor and look at the process tree, consider the process arguments, environment, etc...  Process Create, Process Start events, etc..  You can save it as a PML (all events) and maybe share the file out and link it here?

Comment: If you open the command prompt **elevated as administrator** does that fix the problem?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Run as Admin does not fix

Comment: @HelpingHand i will try it and give result soon

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a console application and came accross this thread, so I wanted to add my update for others that worked for me.

My issue was the .exe I was calling had been configured to run elevated. The cmd prompt I was launching from was not running as an admin and it can't be elevated after it has started. So it would launch a new elevated window to run the command, which would complete in the blink of an eye and then exit leaving me with my non-elevated prompt with no output.

Solution A: Run cmd/powershell as administrator. Then it can run within the same window.
Solution B: Change the .exe to not run as administrator so it doesn't need to launch a new elevated window. This is the option I went with.